# Copy objects from the nested array into the new array in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter, copy

I have a big nested array of objects and each object has an object called 'set. Something like this:

```
const arr1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    subject: 'Subject',
    set: {
      title: 'Title',
      subTitle1: 'SubTitle',
      subTitle2: 'SubTitle',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    subject: 'Subject',
    set: {
      title: 'Title',
      subTitle1: 'SubTitle',
      subTitle2: 'SubTitle',
    },
  },
]
```

I want to get the content of each 'set' object from 'arr1' into the 'arr2', like this:

```
const arr2 = [
  {
    title: 'Title',
    subTitle1: 'SubTitle',
    subTitle2: 'SubTitle',
  },
  {
    title: 'Title',
    subTitle1: 'SubTitle',
    subTitle2: 'SubTitle',
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the set from each object

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    subject: 'Subject',
    set: {
      title: 'Title',
      subTitle1: 'SubTitle',
      subTitle2: 'SubTitle',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    subject: 'Subject',
    set: {
      title: 'Title',
      subTitle1: 'SubTitle',
      subTitle2: 'SubTitle',
    },
  },
]

const arr2 = arr1.map(a => a.set);

console.log(arr2 );
```